# why type(JSON) is str in python?

Tags: python, json, string

I got some data from an API with requests:

```
r = requests.get(...)
a = r.text
print(type(a))
str2JSON = json.dumps(a,indent=4)
print(type(str2JSON))
```

The result is:

```
class 'str'
class 'str'
```

Then I try `loads` instead of `dumps`:

```
str2JSON_2 = json.loads(a)
print(type(str2JSON_2))
```

And I get class `list`!!!

Why is that behaviour?

If you dump a string into JSON and you don’t get an error, does it automatically mean that the JSON is well parsed? Shouldn't that be a JSON class?

Comment: Looks like your result wasn't included in the question

Comment: Did you mean to use `loads` instead of `dumps`?

Comment: The output is correct as the dumps() function (as in dump S) returns a string, as suggested by the S in dumps().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using requests. it provides [convince method to parse your response as json](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) (i.e. it loads it for you) you want `a = r.json()`. This way `a` would be JSON object and you can dump it as string later on. That is assuming you get valid json as response.

here is an example

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users' # dummy resposnse

resp =  requests.get(url)
my_json = resp.json()
#print example user
print(my_json['data'][0])
json_string = json.dumps(my_json, indent=4)
print(json_string)
```

Comment: What do you get there inserting : type(my_json) ?

Comment: try it yourself :-)

Comment: I did: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='reqres.in', port=443)  Max retries exceeded  etc. I can not connect to that API.

Comment: it's just a dummy api. if for whatever reason you cannot connect to it - try with your API url

Comment: < class 'list'>

Comment: after:     my_json = resp.json()         
    print(type(my_json))

Comment: exactly, at top level your response is json array

Answer (score 4):

The thing you get back from requests is a `str` value containing a JSON encoded value.

`dumps` takes that `str` and produces *another* string containing the JSON-encoded version of the original (JSON-encoded) string.

You need `loads` to *decode* the string into a value.

```
json2str = json.loads(a,indent=4)  # name change to reflect the direction of the operation
```

Consider:

```
>>> s = '"foo"'  # A JSON string value
>>> json.dumps(s)
'"\\"foo\\""'
>>> json.loads(s)
'foo'
```

The string may, of course, encode a value other than a simple string:

```
>>> json.loads('3')  # Compare to json.loads('"3"') returning '3'
3
>>> json.loads('[1,2,3]')
[1,2,3]
>>> json.loads('{"foo": 6}')
{'foo': 6}
```

`requests`, though, doesn't actually require you to remember which direction `dumps` and `loads` go (although you should make it a point to learn). A `Response` object has a `json` method which decodes the `text` attribute for you.

```
json2str = r.json()  # equivalent to json2str = json.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps` returns a JSON formatted python string object.

Below the is the statement you can notice in actual implementation file for `def dumps`

> """Serialize `obj` to a JSON formatted `str`.